# noob issue: pivot point not moving while the animated object does

Tags: parent

I will try to post the file later.

All I'm trying to do is to constrain the camera with "track to" to a mesh that is animated and moves around. I bought the mesh online.

The issue is that its pivot point doesn't move at all during the animation, and therefore, when I try track the camera to the object, the camera doesn't move neither. Same issue when I try to parent an empty to it.

How do I fix this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If the mesh you bought online has an armature, it may be because you’re animating the armature, and the position is controlled by a bone as opposed to the mesh’s or armature’s origin. If this is the case, you can set the Track To target to the armature and it should let you select a specific bone.

Comment: Yes that it is the case. The issue is that the armature doesnt appear on the Track To list. EDIT: I just did it but still it doesnt move

Comment: Also, this may just be personal preference, but I often find it’s more convenient to add an Empty and track to that, then parent the empty to whatever you want to follow. That way you can easily make minor adjustments

Comment: I cannot use an empty because I need to pair it with the mesh and I have exactly the same issue with the pivot not moving

Comment: Are you sure you’ve selected the right bone? Does the track to constraint work if you set the target to another object? I’d ask for the blend file but if you bought the model that’s not really an option.

Comment: I've got it. At first I wasnt selecting the right bone, and then I forgot to put Up Y

Comment: thanks so much! really appreciate it

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. :)